# How to obtain a list of available COM interfaces in Windows

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

Is there any way of obtaining a list of registered COM interfaces on a windows machine, with GUIDs?

Before anybody thinks this isn't related to programming, I need this data in order to reference a COM interface in F# (or C#) for interfaces that tlbimp isn't exposing.

Answer (score 0):

There have been a number of applications in this space over the years.

- [COMView](https://www.japheth.de/COMView.html)
- [TypeLibrary Explorer from Embarcadero](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/inspecttypelib_xml.html)
- [Type Library Viewers and Conversion Tools (Microsoft)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/type-library-viewers-and-conversion-tools)
- [PxPlus Type Library Browser](https://manual.pvxplus.com/PXPLUS/PxPlus%20User%20Guide/External%20Components/PxPlus%20Type%20Library%20Browser/Overview.htm)

I used COMView recently. Still works.